# How to calculate output of neural network layers

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

I want to know how I can calculate the output layer from (number of neurons and shape of that) of deep neural network layers. Suppose we have 32 * 32 image input of 2D convolution layer with parameters:

num_filters = 96,
kernel_size = 5,
stride = 1,
pad = 2.

How do I calculate output form or for pooling layer or other layers existing in deep neural networks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formulas are in slide 61 of http://cs231n.stanford.edu/slides/2017/cs231n_2017_lecture5.pdf. The preceding slides describe how they got the formula